# LINQ to Entities how to update a record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Okay, so I'm new to both EF and LINQ. I have figured out how to INSERT and DELETE but for some reason UPDATE seems to escape my grasp.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
EntityDB dataBase = new EntityDB();
Customer c = new Customer
{
     Name = "Test",
     Gender = "Male
};
dataBase.Customers.AddObject(c);
dataBase.SaveChanges();
```

The above creates and adds a record just fine.

```
Customer c = (from x in dataBase.Customers
             where x.Name == "Test"
             selext x).First();
dataBase.Customers.DeleteObject(c);
dataBase.SaveChanges();
```

The above effectively deletes the specified record.

Now how do I update? I can't seem to find an "`UpdateObject()`" method on the entity collection.

Comment: If you are using EF4, I'd prefer this solution

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623672/update-entity-framework-objects

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just modify one of the returned entities:

```
Customer c = (from x in dataBase.Customers
             where x.Name == "Test"
             select x).First();
c.Name = "New Name";
dataBase.SaveChanges();
```

Note, you can only update an entity (something that extends EntityObject, not something that you have projected using something like `select new CustomObject{Name = x.Name}`

Comment: I did that. For some reason it is not persisting the changes to the database.

Comment: @Chevex: But note that it get a lot more involved when using another context instance.

Comment: What does it mean to "use another context instance"?

Comment: I've tried it, but for some reason, in my case it duplicates instead of update. The old record is maintained and a new record is created with the information of the record I suppose to update. What is happening?

Answer (score 8):

//for update

```
(from x in dataBase.Customers
         where x.Name == "Test"
         select x).ToList().ForEach(xx => xx.Name="New Name");
```

//for delete

```
dataBase.Customers.RemoveAll(x=>x.Name=="Name");
```

Answer (score 3):

They both track your changes to the collection, just call the SaveChanges() method that should update the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases @tster's answer will suffice. However, I had a scenario where I wanted to update a row without first retrieving it.

My situation is this: I've got a table where I want to "lock" a row so that only a single user at a time will be able to edit it in my app. I'm achieving this by saying

`update items set status = 'in use', lastuser = @lastuser, lastupdate = @updatetime where ID = @rowtolock and @status = 'free'`

The reason being, if I were to simply retrieve the row by ID, change the properties and then save, I could end up with two people accessing the same row simultaneously. This way, I simply send and update claiming this row as mine, then I try to retrieve the row which has the same properties I just updated with. If that row exists, great. If, for some reason it doesn't (someone else's "lock" command got there first), I simply return FALSE from my method.

I do this by using [context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) which accepts a string command and an array of parameters.

Just wanted to add this answer to point out that there will be scenarios in which retrieving a row, updating it, and saving it back to the DB won't suffice and that there are ways of running a straight update statement when necessary.