# Cannot resolve Symbol ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, resharper

I have getting an Error of "*Cannot Resolve Symbol ObjectStateManager*" when trying to call it on my Database context from Entity Framework 4. I can't find anyone else having this issue. I have tried using **System.Data** and **System.Data.Objects**.

Is there a specific Entity Framework that needs to be made in order to use the ObjectStateManager? Or Am I missing some sort of install package? I am using Database First Entity Framework.

Here is the code it is giving my error: (Line 7)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProfile(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Attach(user);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Profile");
        }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am sure you found a solution by now but I ran into the same issue just now and was able to resolve it by changing the EntityState line to the following:

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 14):

Probably you are using code first EF. In this case you have to revert yours code to explicit implemenatation of IObjectContextAdapter, i.e.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
```

Comment: I am using Database First, I am sad to say that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I also needed to add the namespace: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `System.Data.Entity` assembly to the project?

Also `System.Data.Objects` is correct.

Comment: Since I am using Resharper it says both are not being used even though they are added.

Answer (score 0):

One additional item to check is that the target .net framework for the project is set to .net 4+.

Comment: This may be posted as a comment, or be more specific.